# minikube PROVIDER_DOCKER_NOT_FOUND

Tags: minikube

I'm running Windows 11 and have installed Docker Desktop and it has loaded Docker Engine `v24.0.7`.

This is what I see when I start minikube:

```
    PS C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin> minikube start
  minikube v1.32.0 on Microsoft Windows 11 Home 10.0.22621.2861 Build 22621.2861
✨  Using the docker driver based on user configuration

  Exiting due to PROVIDER_DOCKER_NOT_FOUND: The 'docker' provider was not found: exec: "docker": cannot run executable found relative to current directory
  Suggestion: Install Docker
  Documentation: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/
```

I have tried:

- adding `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin` to the Powershell path. (This is where docker.exe resides.)
- `minikube config set driver` and `minikube delete` followed by `minikube start --driver=docker`

Still getting this `PROVIDER_DOCKER_NOT_FOUND` message.